# styling a php form <input type="submit">

Tags: php, html, css

So I am trying to add some CSS styles to a php form I have the following CSS

```css
#button {
  font-size: 14;
  border:none;
  width:20ex;
  height:10ex;
  outline: none;
}
```

which I would like to add this to the form which is constructed within the p`php` element of the web page using the `id="button"` attribute.

From what I have read this should work.

```
$list = '';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$title = $row['title'];
$id = $row['id'];
$summary = $row['summary'];
//I'm assuming you want each link to be different here...
$list.='<div class="Select_Course"><form name="courseselect" method="post" action="selectedcourse.php">
        <input type="submit" name="subsearch" value="' .$title. '" id="button">
        <input name="submitcourseselection" type="text" value="'.$title.'"hidden> 
        </form>
        <p>' . $summary . '</p></div>';
}
```

However it does not apply the style `#button` from the CSS to this button.

How would i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The button it the submit element of the form

Comment: Do you mean `20px` rather than `20ex;`

Comment: `However it does not apply the style from the CSS to this button.` All of the styles? only one? few?

Comment: can u try using class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your css submit to this. Instead of using an id button

```
input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 15px; 
    font-size: 14px;
    border:none;
    width:20ex;
    height:10ex;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: so the css file would look like `#button input[type=submit]` or just `input[type=submit]`?

Comment: Still wouldn't work because `ex` is not a CSS measurement unit.

Comment: @MarkEriksson Sorry I just copied the css given and didn't noticed that. my bad

Comment: @bdg just `input[type=submit]`

Comment: If it helps add up. Thanks

Comment: why width using ex? better use px  or percentage and don't forget add quotation mark at the end example type="submit"

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz yes It's better to use px but new in my mind that ex is acceptable as css unit like em. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 14;
    border:none;
    width:5em;
    height:2.5em;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Still wouldn't work because `ex` is not a CSS measurement unit.

Comment: @mark-eriksson rofl, i didnt read his css code just edited the selector :P you're right. It should be px or em ..

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was your CSS measurement unit, `ex` is not valid in CSS. Perhaps you meant `px` or `em` but I'm guessing `px` by the value size you provided. This should do the trick

```
#button {
  font-size: 14px; /*added px*/
  border:none;
  width:20px; /*changed to px*/
  height:10px; /*same as above*/
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use button tag and then add css to it's id. You can execute action on button click by javascript $(#yourid).click(function(){
//you action goes here.
});

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me in Firefox(For this example i am using $i since I do not know your Database and i have change the font-size to 15 and echo the list)

```
<style>
#button{
font-size: 15;
border:none;
width:20ex;
height:10ex;
outline: none;
}
</style>

<?php
$list = '';
$i=0; //For this example i am using $i since I do not know your Database 
while($i<6){
$title = 'Title-'.$i;// change this to your database variable $row['title']
$id = $i;// change this to your database variable $row['id']
$summary = 'Summary: '+$i;// change this to your database variable $row['summary']
//I'm assuming you want each link to be different here...
$list.='<div class="Select_Course">
    <form name="courseselect" method="post" action="selectedcourse.php">
    <input type="submit" name="subsearch" value="' .$title. '" id="button">
    <input name="submitcourseselection" type="text" value="'.$title.'"hidden> 
     </form>
    <p>'.$summary.'</p>
    </div>';    
$i++;   

echo $list;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use id also, but in CSS you need to add this code:

```
input[id="button"] {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color:#FF4500;
}
```